# How do you detect packet-loss on Windows Server 2003?

Tags: windows, networking

Is there any way to detect packet loss with the help of performance counters or am I better of using a 3rd-party tool? What tools would you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to track the total number of TCP retries because of packet losses? If so, then yes, Performance Counters will work fine.

Answer (score 9):

netstat -s will show you the total count of retransmissions. Wireshark can capture traffic and got an "expert info" (under Analyze) that will tell you about obious network related errors.

Answer (score 3):

We've always found tools based on the PCAP library to be useful.  In particular Wireshark ([www.wireshark.org](http://www.wireshark.org)) is great for getting a network traffic trace and it will highlight problems such as packet loss in its output.